# Why my border doesn't appear with tailwind (react js)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css, border

There is my jsx file:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { PropTypes } from "prop-types";
import { HashtagIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";

// Fonction pour récup les catégories depuis l'API (remplacée par du dur pr linstant)
const fetchCategories = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const categories = [
        { id: 1, name: "Ressources humaines", icon: "icon" },
        { id: 2, name: "Innovation technologique", icon: "icon" },
        { id: 3, name: "Stratégies marketing", icon: "icon" },
        { id: 4, name: "Amélioration de processus", icon: "icon" },
        { id: 5, name: "Développement durable", icon: "icon" },
        { id: 6, name: "Expérience de clients", icon: "icon" },
        { id: 7, name: "Collaboration / Partenariat", icon: "icon" },
        { id: 8, name: "Formation employés", icon: "icon" },
        { id: 9, name: "Optimisation des coûts", icon: "icon" },
        { id: 10, name: "Diversification des services", icon: "icon" },
        { id: 11, name: "Exploitation des données", icon: "icon" },
        { id: 12, name: "Expansion (national/inter)", icon: "icon" },
        { id: 13, name: "Responsabilité sociale", icon: "icon" },
      ];
      resolve(categories);
    }, 1000);
  });
};

function CategoryList({ onCategorySelect }) {
  const [categoryList, setCategoryList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // charger les categories lors du montage du compo
    fetchCategories().then((categories) => {
      setCategoryList(categories);
    });
  }, []);

  function handleCategorySelect(categoryId) {
    // fonction d'appel du filtrage des idées selon la catégorie sélectionnée
    onCategorySelect(categoryId);
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-wrap">
      {categoryList.map((category) => (
        <div
          key={category.id}
          className="flex items-center justify-center w-1/3 md:w-1/4 lg:w-1/6 p-1 md:p-2 cursor-pointer"
          onClick={() => handleCategorySelect(category.id)}
          onKeyDown={(e) => {
            if (e.key === "Enter" || e.key === " ") {
              handleCategorySelect(category.id);
            }
          }}
          role="button"
          tabIndex={0}
        >
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center bg-orange-500 rounded-lg h-20 border-2 border-gray-700">
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 bg-indigo-200 rounded-full mb-2 mt-1">
              <HashtagIcon className="h-5 w-6" />
            </div>
            <div className="text-xs font-sans font-semibold truncate w-20 text-center">
              <span className="ml-1">{category.name}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

CategoryList.propTypes = {
  onCategorySelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired, // Propriété fonction de rappel pr la sélection de catégorie
};

export default CategoryList;
```

especially in the line "" my borders doesn't appear! even chatGPT don't find the problem, someone can help me?

i tried to use border on other div className but same results, they doesnt appear. So i go on a codesandbox file for try this border and this work normally, i think it's because of all my functions but idk why

Comment: You didn't specify the direction of the border e.g. `border-b` or `border`

Comment: Have you disabled preflights?

Answer (score 0):

I have solution for this, you just need to repeat the CSS I suggest `border-solid border (border-*color*-*number*)` and the border will appear (idk why because normally we don't need to specify two time in tailwind but well...)